# How to save radio button click, when I use *ngFor?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, radio-button

When I click on the radio button, I go to another view (routes) and come back, the radio button is didn't clicked. How to fix it? I use *ngFor to display data of radio buttons.

order-shipping.component.html:

```
<div class="card-header">
  <input type="radio" name='shipping' (click)="calculatePrices.emit(shipping.price)"> {{shipping.name}}
  <p class="card-text"> price: {{shipping.price}}</p>
</div>
```

order-shipping.component.ts:

```
export class OrderShippingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() shipping;
  @Output() calculatePrices = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

order.component.html:

```
<app-order-shipping *ngFor="let shipping of shippings" [shipping]="shipping"
(calculatePrices)="this.cartService.calculatePrices($event)"> </app-order-shipping>
```

order.component.ts:

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  items = {};
  shippings = [];
  constructor(private cartService: CartService, 
  private shippingService: ShippingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();
    this.shippingService.getShipping()
      .subscribe(
        res => this.shippings = res,
        err => console.log(err)
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the typescript file. And what do you mean by "go to another card". Do you have some routes implemented?

Comment: Yes, I mean another view, routes. I edited post by adding ts files.

Comment: "When I click on the radio button, I go to another view (routes) and come back" - Why would a radio button take you to another view? this question will be impossible to solve without understanding your context.

Your best bet is to create an example for us to understand what you mean:
https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: here's a base you can continue edit on:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y9sred?file=src%2Fapp%2Forder%2Forder.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a way to save the selected option on exit. The easiest way is to use a service

We create a simple service with 2 properties, a `BehaviorSubject` and an `Observable` deriving its value from the `BehaviorSubject`

```typescript
export class OrderService {
  constructor() { }
  selectedOrderSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<null | string>(null)
  selectedOrder$ = this.selectedOrderSubject$.asObservable()
}
```

The next step is to read this value `OnInit` and update this value `OnDestroy`

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  shippings = ["Shipping A", "Shipping B"];
  selectedShipping = "";
  destroyed$ = new Subject();

  calculatePrices(shipping) {
    this.selectedShipping = shipping;
    //this.cartService.calculatePrices($event)
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.selectedOrder$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe({
        next: order => (this.selectedShipping = order)
      });
  }
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {}
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.orderService.selectedOrderSubject$.next(this.selectedShipping);
    this.destroyed$.next();
  }
}
```

[See this fork of @SalminSkenderovic stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-natxsy)